# Prepared statements in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How can I run a prepared statement against a database and have the returned rows automatically attach to the entity framework data context? Essentially, how can I achieve the same functionality of `ObjectContext.Execute` except using a prepared SQL command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ObjectContext.Translate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx).